# jBehave eclipse step definition generation java

Tags: java, file, jbehave

Does anyone know if it is possible in jBehave to autogenerate the step definition file  given a user story, I am using Eclipse as my IDE, and using junit 4 as the test framework.

I was hoping there may be something similar to specflow, where you can generate the step definition file from the user story.

Comment: Not familiar how far specflow takes things, but JBehave prints  stub implementations of all unimplemented steps on the console automatically, which you can copy to your steps classes. Would that be what you're looking for?

Comment: So have would you generate those stubs, would exexute the stories using junit from eclipse ?

Comment: See [this tutorial](http://ivanz.com/2011/05/25/java-bdd-with-jbehave-and-watij-in-eclipse-with-junit/) for instance, author is showing how to configure them.